# 'unicode' object has no attribute 'value1'

Tags: python, django, object, attributes

If I have a list of objects in views.py, such as:

```
myobjects=model.objects.all()
```

then I get the values of a field of the objects:

```
times=myobjects.values_list(‘time’, flat=True)
```

and then I want to set attribute to each object of the list times:

```
for mytime in times:
    mytime.value1=myobjects.filter(time=mytime).values_list(‘value1’,flat=true)
    mytime.value2=myobjects.filter(time=mytime).values_list(‘value2’,flat=true)
```

and use the attribute in template html file using:

```
{%for mytime in times%}
<tr><td>{{mytime.value1}}</td><td>{{mytime.value2}}</td></tr>
{%endfor%}
```

It’s giving me an error: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'value1'…(Note: of course also value2). Do I do something else to set the attribute of object mytime? I thought object.attribute=value is enough to set the attribute here. Thanks

**Solution:** I solved my problem using the codes below:

```
objects=model.objects.all()
objects2=objects.filter(type=types[0]) # types is a list i got from user. the codes is used because i want limit type to only one type so that i could get unrepetitive time list later.
timelist=objects2.order_by('time').values('time','date','date_time','anyotherfield')
for mytime in timelist:
    time=objects.filter(time=mytime['time']).values_list('time',flat=True)[0]
    date=objects.filter(time=mytime['date']).values_list('date',flat=True)[0]
    date_time=objects.filter(time=mytime['date_time']).values_list('date_time',
    flat=True)[0]
    myobjects=objects.filter(time=mytime['time']) #to get all objects on each time
    mytime.update({'anyotherfield':myobjects,'date_time':date_time,
    'date':date,'time':time})
return render_to_response('report.html',locals())
```

In the html page I write:

```
{%for mytime in timelist%}
<tr>
    <td>{{mytime.date_time}}</td>
    <td>{{mytime.date}}</td>
    <td>{{mytime.time}}</td>

    {%for object in mytime.anyotherfield%}
    <td>{{object.value1}}</td>
    <td>{{object.value1}}</td>
    {%endfor%}
</tr>
{%endfor%}
```

so that I could get one row for each different time('date_time'), and in each row I display the time information(one and only one for each time field) and the specific field values for different objects on that specific time.

Answer (score 3):

myobjects.values_list() returns a list of unicode values, not objects. If you need to augment the values with values from your queryset, you might consider returning a dictionary of values instead of the values_list...

```
times = myobjects.values('time')

for mytime in times:
    mytime.update({'my_key' : myobjects.filter(time=mytime).values_list('value1',flat=true)})
```

Hope that helps you out.

Comment: now it's giving me 'ValuesQuerySet' object has no attribute 'iteritems'. Is there something wrong with objects.values() or with .iteritems()?

Comment: Still, it says: 'ValuesQuerySet' object has no attribute 'items'. Maybe it does not need .items()?

Comment: I believe you're right:http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#values and I need more coffee :)

Comment: You *should* be able to add as many values to the dictionary as you need without upsetting the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why you pass a flattened queryset (`values_list`) to the template at all?

As Brandon mentioned you would be better off if you put your data in a dict:

```
myobjects=model.objects.all()
times=myobjects.values_list(‘time’, flat=True)

time_info = {}

for mytime in times:
    time_info[mytime] = myobjects.filter(time=mytime)
```

And then in your template:

```
{% for time, myobjects in time_info.items %}
<h1>{{ time }}</h1>
<ul>
{% for myobject in myobjects %} 
    <li>{{ myobject.value }}</li> 
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I added the solution to the question, u could c now why i have to use values_list